# conflicting types for typedef

Tags: c, struct, header, typedef

I try to build ADT in C. For example, while implementing a stack containing elements of type `int`. I will put `typedef int item_t`  in the header file, so that I can change only one line to use the same  stack to store `double` elements.

When I implement a binary tree, I use the same skill. For example, I declare a node in `node.h` as following

```
typedef struct node_t *link_t;
typedef int item_t;
struct node_t {
    item_t item;
    link_t left;
    link_t right;
};
```

Now, I use `typedef int item_t` in `node.h`. If I want to use a stack to store elements of type `link_t` declared in `node.h`, and just treat them as `item_t`. What should I do?

I can't just do such as follows in stack.h

```
#include "node.h"
typedef link_t item_t;
```

because I have typedef item_t in node.h, and the compiler will complains. `conflicting types for ‘item_t’`

Answer (score 1):

Making an ADT in C is both easy, fun and a good learning experience. However, you can't make a truly generic ADT in any C-based language that can be reused for different ADTs, you have to make a separate structure for each ADT.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to solve this problem by way of a broad copy-paste.  If you want to store three `link_t`'s in a BST according to your `node_t` model here, then you'll have to define a new struct with a new name.  (You could also use unions to store either a `link_t` or an `item_t` in each element of the BST, but that may be overly complicated for your purposes.)

Answer (score 0):

No, what you are trying to do is not logical. You are telling compiler to typedef 2 different things (int and link_t) to 1 thing (item_t). That does not make sense.